# link ocilib using mingw g++ on windows

Tags: oracle, gcc, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

i'm trying to use ocilib.h that i downloaded from the internet. It work just find went i using visual studio 2017. But because of my machine i have to use mingw.

Windows 10   - OS
VSCode       - Text Editor
Mingw        - Compiler
Language     - C/C++
External Lib - ocilib

I use to the g++ -g *.cpp -o main.exe only, never tried the complex command to link library

my current directory is : C:\Users----\Desktop\Testing

[the code that i copy from the developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw6B1.png)

the header location is :  C:\ocilib\include (for all the *.h and *.cpp)
[what inside this directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tswu.png)

the link location is :  C:\ocilib\lib32 (for all the *.dll and *.lib)
[what inside this last dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBaWA.png)

i have try the -l -L -I command but bunch of error still come out

Please help me...Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using the same `.lib` in g++ and Visual Studio? Without the error message you get I have to use my paranormal sphere. Get rid of the images and just show the code or file list.

Comment: Yes same .lib for g++ and Visual Studio.

Comment: compilers use different name mangling so very unlikely g++ will handle the VS ones, this goes for the .lib and .dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the ocilib driver from http://vrogier.github.io/ocilib/ and build it with gcc. I had no issues building it under MSYS2 with MinGW-w64 from http://winlibs.com/

Comment: Thanks I already using that thing for alternative for 2 month now .hehehe